# Android Library Projects and Unit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I am developing an Android library for interacting with a web service, and I am trying to develop some unit tests to check how well this works.

When I run the specified tests, I get the following error:

```
[2012-07-19 15:12:09 - MMWebAPI] Could not find MMWebAPI.apk!
[2012-07-19 15:12:10 - MMWebAPITest] Test run failed: Unable to find instrumentation target package: com.webapi.mmwebapi
```

Where the `MMWebAPI` is the library, and does not produce a `.apk`.

I am looking for definitive guide for unit testing Android projects, specifically, what can and can not be tested (in this case, network operations are the core of the library), a step by step tutorial would be a great help also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android testing framework doesn't allow to test Android library without application project that depends on that library. Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173034/265597).

You can find good introduction to testing Android project [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html). If your code doesn't use android-specific method You can use JUnit for tests + some mocking library. Among other testing framework [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) and [Robolectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) seems to be most popular.

Answer (score 3):

What this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173034/265597) mentions in an update is probably what's explained step-by-step [here](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2012/04/android-testing-library-projects.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your instrumentation tag is under manifest tag not application tag

Comment: please improve your answer by adding more details