# How to properly mock HttpGet call on Android test

Tags: android, unit-testing, http, mocking, robotium

I've got an application that performs HTTP GET calls using [`HttpGet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) and I would like to mock the response in order to test different scenarios without having to setup any specific local server that would act like the remote one.

The goal is to have very high level tests that acts like a real user ([Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)) and fake the response that the application would obtain calling the real server. Much like testing a Twitter client, if you need an example.

Comment: I use Robolectric's FakeHttpLayer mock the http request and response, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136682/how-to-unit-test-a-class-that-uses-httpclient-in-android-using-the-built-in-fram/10140818#10140818) for sample usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this is what I did to get fake HttpResponses in my Robotium tests:
- I have a class HttpCallBuilder, that usually just returns a DefaultHttpClient
- I added a setHttpClient() method to set a MockHttpClient in my tests (you need to implement (empty) a lot of methods in the HttpClient interface, which I omitted here):

```
public class MockHttpClient implements HttpClient {

private static Context context;
private final BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

@Override
public HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request) throws IOException,
        ClientProtocolException {
    InputStream mockInputStream = context.getAssets().open(
            MockResponses.forRequest(request));
    return new MockHttpResponse(mockInputStream);
}

@Override
public HttpParams getParams() {
    return params;
}

public static void setContext(Context applicationContext) {
    MockHttpClient.context = applicationContext;
}
}
```

MockResponses allows you to prime your Mock with the right responses for the situation:

```
public class MockResponses {

private static final List<String[]> responseMapping = new ArrayList<String[]>();
private static final String BASE = "mocks/";

public static String forRequest(final HttpUriRequest request) {
    final String requestString = request.getURI().toString();
    for (final String[] mapping : responseMapping) {
        if (requestString.matches(mapping[0])) {
            return BASE + mapping[1];
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "No mocked reply configured for request: " + requestString);
}

public static void forRequestDoAnswer(final String regex,
        final String fileToReturn) {
    responseMapping.add(new String[] { regex, fileToReturn });
}

public static void reset() {
    responseMapping.clear();
}
}
```

In your test you can then prepare your test like this:

```
HttpCallBuilder.setHttpClient(new MockHttpClient());
MockHttpClient.setContext(context);
MockResponses.reset();
MockResponses.forRequestDoAnswer(".*method=Login.*", "loginform.html");
```

Answer (score 2):

Google provides a library named as Mockwebserver which can be used for mocking web service response. https://code.google.com/p/mockwebserver/ You can refer this link

Comment: Why is this getting a downvote? MockWebServer (which is not moved to okhttp project) seems to be a perfectly valid way to do what the OP has asked for.

Comment: Well, it's not provided by Google. It's just hosted on Google Code.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) ?

According to [this article](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/10/mockito-android.html) its latest version should support dalvik, so you should be able to use it with robotium.

With mockito you can mock any object to return whatever you want. I found it very powerful and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Try XML Mimic, that will solve your problem. It is easy to configure and runs as independent server.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlmimic/