# Using Robolectric, how to test JSON values sent along POST *request*

Tags: java, android, testing, apache-commons-httpclient, robolectric

In my app I'm going to be sending JSON in a POST request to the server.

I want to test to make sure I'm sending the right values.

Since I'm using Robolectric, my conclusion is that I should get the **request** that is being sent to the FakeHttpLayer, pull out the JSON, and test that it matches my expectations.

Sounds simple, but I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how to see what JSON I've POSTed.

My code vaguely looks like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try{
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://google.com");
    json.put("blah", "blah");
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "JSON: " + json.toString());
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    post.setEntity(se);
    response = client.execute(post);
} catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to have something which is like

```
assertTrue(myRequestJSON.matches("blah"));
```

But I can't seem to get that using anything inside of

```
Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().getLastSentHttpRequestInfo();
```

...or any of the other variations on that.

Help?

By the way, I'm certainly open to thinking about this in a different way, if you think my testing approach is misguided.

Thank you!

EDIT: I realized I had "myResponseJSON" in my dummy code rather than "myRequestJSON," which may have made it unclear--fixed.

Comment: I will add, [PostBodyMatcher](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/javadoc/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/tester/org/apache/http/FakeHttpLayer.RequestMatcherBuilder.PostBodyMatcher.html) seems promising, but I'm not really sure how to use it...

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136682/how-to-unit-test-a-class-that-uses-httpclient-in-android-using-the-built-in-fram/10140818#10140818) helps.

Comment: Thanks yorkw--but unfortunately I've seen that one, and as far as I can tell it's testing JSON in the context of responses, not requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was completely wrong in my previous solution.  You can do this rather simply it would appear.  I found the solution (predictably) in the Robolectric example code:

```
HttpPost sentHttpRequest = (HttpPost) Robolectric.getSentHttpRequest(0);
StringEntity entity = (StringEntity) sentHttpRequest.getEntity();
String sentPostBody = fromStream(entity.getContent());
assertThat(sentPostBody, equalTo("a post body"));
assertThat(entity.getContentType().getValue(), equalTo("text/plain; charset=UTF-8"));
```

(from [here](https://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/pivotallabs/api/HttpTest.java))