# Mock rest API call using Robolectric in Unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, robolectric, spring-android

Hi guys Im using *Robolectric* and *Mockito* and mockito in unit testing, I have come to a point that I need to verify data that depends on a api request call.

How do you code  so that your Rest api calls will use mock data when running unit test?

Inside my StockFragment.java, I use *SpringAndroid* + *Robospice* to perform a Rest Api call. 

Also I have a RequestListener(from Robospice) inside the fragment that updates the UI in the fragment if the request is successful or not.

Here is my fragment:

```
   public class StockFragment extends RoboDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        displayStockInfo();
    }

    private void displayStockInfo(){
        request = new MyRequest();
        request.setQuote(getStock().getSymbol());
        lastRequestCacheKey = request.createCacheKey();
        ((BaseActivity)getActivity()).getSpiceManager().execute(request, lastRequestCacheKey, DurationInMillis.ALWAYS_EXPIRED, new MyRequestListener());
    }

    private class MyRequestListener implements RequestListener<PseStocksResponse> {
        @Override
        public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException e) {
            //show toast about failure reason ...
        }
        @Override
        public void onRequestSuccess(PseStocksResponse pseStocksResponse) {
            //UPDATE UI VIEWS ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Robolectric Test class.

```
   public class StockFragmentTest {
    MyRequest request;
    Stock stock;
    StockFragment stockFragment;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        stockFragment = new StockFragment();
        FragmentTestUtil.startFragment(stockInfoFragment);
        FragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment(stockInfoFragment);
        findViews();
    }

    public void findViews(){
        quoteTextView = (TextView)stockInfoFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.quoteTextView);
        nameTextView = (TextView)stockInfoFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.nameTextView );
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void viewShouldNotBeNull(){
        assertNotNull(quoteTextView);
        assertNotNull(nameTextView);
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void showDisplayedInfo(){
        //TODO: Assert textview.getText() values here
    }
}
```

One solution I am thinking is have **testMode** flag in the StockFragment and do some conditional statements that will return test data if true, but I think there is a better way to test.

 I think I need to listen to Http requests on my Test class and catch that request then provide mock data, Im not sure though. 

 **Note**: Robolectric is setup and is confirmed working and tested. Though I did not include them in the code snippet above.
Roboguice is also used as injections.

Comment: I would avoid modifying code to know about test presence

Comment: This also will fail with `ClassCastException` since `FragmentTestUtil` will try to attach fragment to instance of `Activity` not `BaseActivity`

Comment: But before it will fail with `StubException` because you need to use `RobolectricTestRunner`

Comment: Robolectric is setup properly and does not fail with Stubexception , I just did not include it in the code above. For the ClassCastException, what is your suggested way?

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use dependency injection framework like `Dagger`. It could take a long time to figure out how framework works. Take a look to examples.

I would also encourage you remove network logic from views. Keep it in `Activity`.

Also (optionally) I would hide notion about usage of specific network framework - `RoboSpice`.

As for now you could fix test with next steps.

Use Robolectric to run tests:

```
@RunWith( RobolectricTestRunner.class )
@Config( reportSdk = 18, emulateSdk = 18 )
public class StockFragmentTest {...}
```

Add mock for `SpiceManager`:

```
...
public class StockFragmentTest 
{
    @Mock
    SpiceManager mockedSpiceManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
        throws Exception
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Create test activity:

```
public class StockFragmentTest 
{
    ...
    public class TestBaseActivity extends BaseActivity 
    {
        @Override
        SpiceManager getSpiceManager() 
        {
            return mockedSpiceManager;
        }
    }
}
```

Use test activity:

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
    ...
    stockFragment = new StockFragment();
    FragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment( stockFragment, TestBaseActivity.class, <id of placeholder in xml for BaseActivity> );
    ...
}
```

I think the last snippet is not applicable for you code. You probably have `StockActivity`. So you should make `TestStockActivity` by analogy and replace usage of `BaseTestActivity`. However I would expect more side effects from this approach. The proper dependency injection will help

Comment: Hi Eugene, you're right the ClassCastException happens. I am using Roboguice for injections. Can you give links to resources/articles containing more details or tutorials? The concept is still too broad for me.

Comment: Here is how to use `RoboGuice` with fragments: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Your-First-Injected-Fragment

Comment: Here is how to do POJO injection: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Your-First-POJO-Injection

Comment: Here is how to define binding: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Your-First-Custom-Binding

Comment: Here is how to override injections in test: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/astroboy/src/test/java/org/roboguice/astroboy/activity/AstroboyMasterConsoleTest.java

Comment: Hi thanks Eugen, Ill definitely take a look on these.

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric contains already a fake http layer where you can prepare answers.

Details and example can be found in the answers at  [Android http testing with Robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816395/android-http-testing-with-robolectric)