# Robolectric junit test - missing internet permission

Tags: android, junit, robolectric, roboguice

I am developing some JUnit test for ma app. 
I need to use Robolectric + Roboguice libraries. What I am trying to do now is only simple test which checks if activity is not null.

Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP,
        application = TestBoomerangManagerApplication.class,
manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class SimpleTest {

    private DirectInviteEmployeesActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(DirectInviteEmployeesActivity
                .class).create().get();

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() {
        assertThat(activity).isNotNull();

        Button button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_send_invites);
        assertThat(button).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFail() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

It is really simple and should work, but when I am trying to run my test it comes with error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INTERNET permission is required.
    at com.segment.analytics.Analytics$Builder.<init>(Analytics.java:597)
    at com.segment.analytics.Analytics.with(Analytics.java:116)
    at com.jobtapteam.shared.utils.AnalyticsUtil.sendPageView(AnalyticsUtil.java:90)
    at com.jobtapteam.shared.ui.AbstractActivity.onCreate(AbstractActivity.java:153)
    at com.jobtapteam.employer.ui.activity.DirectInviteEmployeesActivity.onCreate(DirectInviteEmployeesActivity.java:73)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
    at SimpleTest.setup(SimpleTest.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Obviously I have added Internet permission to manifest file.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help ! :)

Comment: Remove manifest from your `@Config`. 99% Robolectric picks up correct manifest with  `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do real http requests with robolectric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475998/is-it-possible-to-do-real-http-requests-with-robolectric)

Comment: Possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190822/roboelectric-is-giving-me-a-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-internet-permiss/34634842#34634842